# Simple math isn't working in php function if called through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am running a WordPress site and recently tried to implement a like-dislike system. Everything works fine ... post meta updates perfectly. I can show updated `like/dislike` count using json_encode. My PHP function code is something like this(it's called when a specific div is clicked) -

```
    $post_likes = array(
$current_user->ID => array(
             'date' => date("d/m/Y"), 
             'IP' => get_client_ip())
             );  
    $new_likes = array(
             'date' => date("d/m/Y"), 
             'IP' => get_client_ip());
    $post_likes[$current_user->ID] = $new_likes;
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_likes_id', $post_likes );
    $output_count = count(get_post_meta( $post_id, "post_likes_id", true ));
    $output = array( 'likecount' => $output_count );
    echo json_encode( $output );
    exit();
```

The above code works perfectly and shows the updated post like count when clicked on a specific div using json_encode. 
What I am currently trying to do is -

```
$output_count = count(get_post_meta( $post_id, "post_likes_id", true )) - count(get_post_meta( $post_id, "post_dislikes_id", true ));
```

I am trying to get the difference between like and dislike counts instead of just like count. Which doesn't work. It doesn't show any change when clicked on the specific div which calls the ajax. (It does update the `post_likes_id` meta).

Could anyone please tell me what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

If you need more data, like the jquery code and the full function, I will post that in the comment.

Comment: Please print  count(get_post_meta( $post_id, "post_likes_id", true ))  and count(get_post_meta( $post_id, "post_dislikes_id", true ) these individually

Comment: What is this meant to do `array_push($post_likes[$current_user->ID] = $new_likes);` ?

Comment: If I print those individually and put them both in json_encode, I can do the math using jquery which calls this function. But why wouldn't a simple math work inside php while called though ajax? The same thing works if not called through ajax. Any explanation? Thanks @Gufran Hasan

Comment: `$post_likes = get_post_meta( $post_id, "post_likes_id", true );
$new_likes = array(some array data I am saving);`
so basically when the function is called, it pushes the current user ID into post meta. @billynoah

Comment: I would be very careful - I'm going to quickly break down the piece of code @billynoah pointed out. `$post_likes[$current_user->ID] = $new_likes` This is an assignment. Single `=` sign is an assignment operator. This should assign and then will return true. We then push that true to an array `array_push(true)`. That is because the assignment of `$new_likes` into `$post_likes[$current_user->ID]` will have returned true, that is the value we push to the array.
It seems to me that what you intend to do is replace the equals sign with a comma?

Comment: Array push does not take a single parameter. The first parameter is the array to push to, and everything that comes after will be pushed to that array. In your code, you only have a single parameter in array_push. Whether that is causing your problem or not, it is definitely a problem.

Comment: @Michael Thompson No, the array push works perfectly what I need. This is what I am doing - `$post_likes = array(
 $current_user->ID => array(
                 'date' => date("d/m/Y"), 
                 'IP' => get_client_ip())
     ); ` 
This whole array inside array is in the post meta and I am pulling that post meta, pushing another key with array inside that post meta. It works fine and I don't have any questions about that. My problem starts when I try to count the keys of $post_likes and subtract it by another count($array) thingy.

Comment: @Michael Thompson so I need to use comma to push a key with array for that key value  into an array instead of equal?

Comment: Yes, as per the array_push webpage in PHP documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php
In PHP, function parameters are separated by a single comma.

Comment: @Michael Thompson Please see this image - https://imgur.com/a/UvmBQ4m
If I use `array_push($post_likes[$current_user->ID] , $new_likes);` i get this. Also the value isn't stored. If I use equal instead of comma, it saves with the IP and date as key value. I am lost!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170509/discussion-between-asifur-rahman-and-michael-thompson).